# Not able to download zip or exe directly but only as oleObject.bin from word docx file using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using `XWPFDocument` to parse a Word docx which contains zip, .exe, .docx, .xlsx files all embedded.
I'm able to download .docx, and .xlsx files successfully using `PackagePart` of the `XWPFDocument`, whereas zip and exe files are getting converted during the download as oleObject[1...4].bin and I am unable to reconvert to the original file name and properties.
How do I maintain the original zip/.exe files name and properties?

I also compared the MD5Sum of the original .exe and the converted from code oleObject.bin  and they are completely different.

```java
    public void extractEmbeddedFiles(String filePath) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        InputStream is = getFileFromResourceAsStream(filePath);

        OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(is);

        List<PackagePart> packageParts = opcPackage.getParts();

        for (PackagePart packagePart : packageParts) {
            System.out.println(packagePart.getPartName().toString());

            if (packagePart.getPartName().getName().contains("/word/")) {
                try {
                    InputStream is1 = packagePart.getInputStream();
                    long n = 254;
                    is1.skip(n);
                    WordExtractorTest test = new WordExtractorTest();
                    test.test(packagePart);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception occurred :" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

I am able to read the embedded files as oleObject.bin but not able to read the original zip/exe format

Also, I am unable to get the original file name and properties. How to get original file name properties of the embedded exe's, zip files from `XWPFDocument`, or how to get the original file from the word docx using `XWPFDocument`. While I compared the MD5Sum of the exe after manually directly copying it from the word docx and oleObject.bin generated from the code are completely different

I wanted to get the exact file .exe or .zip from the docx file using `XWPFDocument`. Please let me know of any code examples or code extracts that can do this.

Comment: It is hard to tell without a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you try with Apache Tika, does that manage to extract the inner embedded files?

Comment: I have provided the example of what I am trying to do. The filePath refers to a word docx and I am reading the packagePart of a word docx and trying to parse the /word/embeddings

Answer (score 1):

Embedded document parts named `oleObject*.bin` and of content type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleObject` are files in [POIFSFileSystem](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.html) format.

So if the part name's content type is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleObject`, then the part should read into a `POIFSFileSystem`. Having this, we can get the root node and iterating over all entries in this. If entry  is instance of `org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentEntry`, then this is an embedded document file. If the name of that `DocumentEntry` contains "Ole10Native", then this is a `org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.Ole10Native`. The bytes of that `Ole10Native` can be got via `Ole10Native.getDataBuffer`. Most times the file name is stored in `Ole10Native.getLabel`.

Sometimes the entry is named "CONTENTS" only. In this case the bytes can be read via `org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentInputStream`. But the name and the type of that file seems not be stored in this case. So the only way to get the file type then will be get the file type out of the first bytes (magic bytes).

Complete example, which works for me using current Apache POI 5.2.3. `WordDocumentHavingEmbeddings.docx` must contain some embedded files in its body.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class XWPFReadOleObjectsBin {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("./WordDocumentHavingEmbeddings.docx");
                
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(in); 
  
  int fileNameIndex = 1;
  
  for (org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart embeddedPart : document.getAllEmbeddedParts()) {
   System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
   System.out.println("PackagePart: " + embeddedPart.getContentType());
   if ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleObject".equals(embeddedPart.getContentType())) {
    org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem filesystem = new org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem(embeddedPart.getInputStream());
    org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode rootNode = filesystem.getRoot();
    for (org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.Entry entry : rootNode) {
     System.out.println("Entry: " + entry);
     System.out.println("Entry name:" + entry.getName());
     if (entry instanceof org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentEntry) {
      org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentEntry documentEntry = (org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentEntry)entry;
      org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.Ole10Native ole10Native = null;
      if (documentEntry.getName().contains("Ole10Native")) {   
       try { // fails for linked Ole10Native
        ole10Native = org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.Ole10Native.createFromEmbeddedOleObject(rootNode);
       } catch (Exception e) {
        continue;
       }
       System.out.println("Ole10Native command:" + ole10Native.getCommand());
       System.out.println("Ole10Native fileName:" + ole10Native.getFileName());
       System.out.println("Ole10Native label:" + ole10Native.getLabel());
       String fileName = ole10Native.getLabel();
       if (fileName == null) fileName = "unknownOle10Native" + fileNameIndex++ + ".nul";
       byte[] data = ole10Native.getDataBuffer();
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./" + fileName);
       out.write(data);
       out.close();
      } else if (documentEntry.getName().contains("CONTENTS")) {        
       org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentInputStream documentInputStream = filesystem.createDocumentInputStream(documentEntry.getName());
       String fileName = "unknownCONTENTS" + fileNameIndex++ + ".nul";
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./" + fileName);
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       int len;
       while ((len = documentInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
       }
       out.close();
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

---

There might be embedded parts in other package parts except the document body too. That could be headers and footers, comments, footnotes and endnotes and so on. Those parts would not be got via `XWPFDocument.getAllEmbeddedParts`. To really get all embedded parts, one would must change code above like so:

```
...
  //for (org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart embeddedPart : document.getAllEmbeddedParts()) {
  org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage opcPackage = document.getPackage();
  for (org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart embeddedPart : opcPackage.getParts()) {
...
```

Comment: I have one more clarification on how to extract the same document from end notes or foot notes of word doc in XWPFDocument

Comment: @Code Trickle: See my supplement.

Comment: Thanks a lot Axel, Your code example helped to unblock from a really blocking issue for me in XWPFDocument parsing.

Comment: Hi Axel,   I am trying to parse .doc 2003 format in apache poi and able to extract embedded .exe, .zip., .tar, .so files from it as it is Ole10Native object but I am unable to parse and get the embedded .ppt, .pptx , .docx , .pdf files from parent .doc file. I can give you the code which i tried in the answer part, can you review it and let know where i got it wrong